# Is it feasible to run inline jQuery script inside a WordPress page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is it not possible to run jQuery in the middle of a page (inline)?

I tried to run this code inside a custom WordPress template....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
  jQuery(".upb_row_bg").css("filter","blur(30px)");
});
</script>
```

However it seems to have no affect on the element in question.  In fact if cannot even select the element -
 console.log('jQuery(".upb_row_bg).length; shows 0.

If I put the same code right before the closing  tag after the wordpress wp_footer() function, it works.  If I place it before wp_footer, then it does not.

Any ideas?  I have another script on another page where I was able to use a simple inline script that is generated by a wordpress filter...

```
<script>jQuery( "figure" ).replaceWith( "<div class=\”new-class\”>” + jQuery( "figure" ).html() + "</div>" );</script>
```

This works as expected even though with this snippet there is no event to trigger it, it just runs and replaced the preceding  element. So inline scripts must work.

I am a bit confused.

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Is `.upb_row_bg` a static element already present or is it generated dynamically?

Comment: It is static (well generated by a WordPress plugin).  There are no errors in the console.

Comment: well seems that the `.upb_row_bg` element is not "printed" to the DOM by the time you run the code.

Comment: Make sense.  Anyway to test that?

Comment: Best practice is to put the scripts right before the closing `</body>` tag for reasons like this. You can test this by creating a static HTML file with a single `<p>` element in the body. Then run `console.log($('p').length)` once before the element and once after. The results should show `0` and `1`.

Comment: Thanks... I will look at the placement of the script.  Or at least use an event like on('load..

Comment: This is interesting as `$(document).ready()` should fire once the DOM is fully loaded. Out of curiosity what happens if you replace it with `$( window ).on( "load", function()` - I shouldn't expect it to make a difference as that should only be waiting for images/iframes etc. but worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks strange.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.upb_row_bg').css('filter', 'blur(30px)');
});
</script>
```

`'figure'` does not look like a valid selector, use a class or ID.

As far as what you're trying to accomplish with your second code snippet just do:

```
<script>$('#figure').addClass('new-class')</script>
```

---

Or, if you really need `figure` to be out of the question

```
<script>$('.figure').addClass('new-class'); $('.new-class').removeClass('figure')</script>
```

Comment: 'figure' is an HTML tag that is used by WooCommerce (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/product-image.php).  This code snippet was an example that inline jQuery was working.  That snippet replaces the figure tag with a div (and a new class).

The problem I was having was with first code block I posted.  But it turns out that the DOM wasn't ready when the code was called.  Firing it with jQuery(window).load(function() fixed that.